# Shell script loop through file, ssh into remote server and copy files continue on fail

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

Given the following file, I cannot figure out how to continue to iterate through the lines one by one without it exiting on first failure of the inner most remote ssh command.

The basic premise is this script ssh's to a remote server defined as `INPUT_FILE` as `USER` and copies a bunch of files off to a remote location for backup.. the actual backup script is in `backup.sh`. which `controller.sh` executes.

My problem is that if the backup.sh throws an error, something like a permission denied for `cp` the whole `while` loop finishs and it won't connect to any of the remaing servers in my `INPUT_FILE`. I know this because I have purposely put in place permissions on various servers to test this scenario.

How can i iterate through the files, and wait for the first ssh command to complete and force it to go to the next line without exiting.

### controller.sh

```
INPUT_FILE=$1
USER=$2
SCRIPT_DIR=/opt/sapdownloads/MikesUtilities/backups
BACKUP_DIR=$SCRIPT_DIR/data
DATE=`date +%m%d%y`
LOG_FILE=$SCRIPT_DIR/logs/backup.controller.log


##
# Create The Log dir and log files
##
function log(){
   echo -e ${*}
   echo -e "[${USER}][`date`] - ${*}" >> ${LOG_FILE}
}


#Iterate through the input file line by line

cat $INPUT_FILE | while read l;do {
   #Split the line by spaces into an array
   line=($l)
   #make sure server is lower case
   SERVER=`echo ${line[1]} | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]`
   #make sure tier is uppercase
   TIER=`echo ${line[0]} | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`
   log "###################################"
   log "#  Tier: $TIER | SERVER: $SERVER  #"
   log "###################################"
   log "Making Sure we can login to the Server"
   CHK=`ssh -t -q -o "BatchMode yes" -o "ConnectTimeout 5" -l $USER $SERVER "echo success"`;
   if [ "success" = $CHK ] >/dev/null 2>&1
   then
      CPDIR=$BACKUP_DIR/$TIER/$SERVER/$DATE
      log "Creating new backup directories in $CPDIR"
      #make the new backup directory in $BACKUP_DIR
      mkdir -p $BACKUP_DIR/$TIER/$SERVER/$DATE/etc
      mkdir -p $BACKUP_DIR/$TIER/$SERVER/$DATE/home


      log "Executing Remote Backup Script"
      ret=`ssh -n -t -q -o "BatchMode yes" -o "ConnectTimeout 5" -l $USER $SERVER "/bin/bash $SCRIPT_DIR/backup.sh $CPDIR; echo $?"`
      echo "return: [$ret]"
      if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then
         echo "Success. Aborting"
         break
      fi
   else
      printf "${i}\tUnable to connect to host\n" >> $ERRORS;
   fi
} </dev/null; done
```

### backup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
CPDIR=$1
DATE=`date +%m%d%y`
SCRIPT_DIR=/opt/sapdownloads/MikesUtilities/backups
LOG_FILE=$SCRIPT_DIR/logs/backup.log
SIDADM_HOME=/home/${sapsid}adm
ORASID_HOME=/home/ora${sapsid}
ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle
cpErrors=()
message=""
SENDTO="joe@example.com"
SENDFROM="team@example.com"

##
# Create The Log dir and log files
##
function log(){
   #echo -e ${*}
   echo -e "[${USER}][`date`] - ${*}" >> ${LOG_FILE}
}

function compileMessage(){
   message="Unable to CP one or more files from the server $HOSTNAME \n\n"
   for i in "${cpErrors[@]}"
   do
      message+="${i}\n"
   done
}

function sendMail(){
   compileMessage

   echo -e $message | mail -s "OS Backup Errors" -r $SENDFROM $SENDTO
}

cd /etc
#copy fstab
if [ -d "oratab" ]; then
   log "Copying oratab to $CPDIR/etc"
   cp oratab $CPDIR/etc
fi
#Copy fstab
if [ -d "fstab" ]; then
   log "Copying fstab to $CPDIR/etc"
   cp fstab $CPDIR/etc
fi

#make sure that folder exists first
if [ -d "$ORASID_HOME" ]; then

   #Test to make sure we can access the folder
   if [ -w "$ORASID_HOME" ]; then
      log "Copying $ORASID_HOME to $CPDIR/home"
      cp -rf $ORASID_HOME $CPDIR/home
   else
      #if we cant access that folder, send an email
      log "Unable to cp $ORASID_HOME to $CPDIR/home"
      cpErrors+=($ORASID_HOME)
   fi

fi

#make sure that folder exists first
if [ -d "$SIDADM_HOME" ]; then

   #Test to make sure we can access the folder
   if [ -w "$SIDADM_HOME" ]; then
      log "Copying $SIDADM_HOME to $CPDIR/home"
      cp -rf $SIDADM_HOME $CPDIR/home
   else
      #if we cant access that folder, send an email
      log "Unable to cp $SIDADM_HOME to $CPDIR/home"
      cpErrors+=($SIDADM_HOME)
   fi

fi

#make sure that folder exists first
if [ -d "$ORACLE_HOME" ]; then

   #Test to make sure we can access the folder
   if [ -w "$ORACLE_HOME" ]; then
      log "Copying $ORACLE_HOME to $CPDIR/home"
      cp -rf $ORACLE_HOME $CPDIR/home
   else
      #if we cant access that folder, send an email
      log "Unable to cp $ORACLE_HOME to $CPDIR/home"
      cpErrors+=($ORACLE_HOME)
   fi

fi


if [ ${#cpErrors[@]} != 0 ]; then
   log "Sending Email of cp errors"
   sendMail
fi
```

Comment: The name class should be `[[:lower:]]` instead of `[:lower:]`

Comment: Is this something that `scp` would be useful for your needs?

Comment: scp seems useful but im copying several files for each server in various locations like `/etc/fstab` `/etc/oratab` and a few `/home` directories. The location theyre backing up to is an NFS share on all the servers. It seems illogical to use SCP when i could just run a shell script on each server to use `cp` and save connections and bandwidth.

Comment: @gorelative Why do the copy2home chunks test for write permission on the source directory? #codereview

Comment: @gorelative  Something odd happening in the three chunks that actually copy data to `$CPDIR/home` - the code ignores directories that don't exist, counts non-writable directories as errors, but ignores any errors during the actual `cp` command.  Ergo, `cpErrors` is named incorrectly; it does not record `cp` errors.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld first iteration of my code, thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably have guessed, `ssh` is eating your input from the while loop, and that's why it's failing. Actually I'm not 100% sure why `-n` is not working in this case, but we can work around it.

Since I don't have your backup scripts (nor the general setup), I simplified the script quite a bit, but I think the general idea is same. Go through input file that server information, and try to find a server we can login to, and then see if we can successfully execute a script there

I call a simple script on a remote machine that waited for couple of seconds, and returned an `exit code`. You should add some exit codes to your `Backup.sh`, so that you can check what was returned from the remote command, and then act on it.

So with adding **curly braces** to the while (and `</dev/null`), and retrieve **exit code** from your remote script, I was able to go through the list until a successful remote script execution was done:

```
cat $INPUT_FILE | while read l;do {

SERVER=($l)
CHK=`ssh -t -q -o "BatchMode yes" -o "ConnectTimeout 5" -l $USER $SERVER "echo success"`;

if [ "success" = $CHK ] >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  ret=`ssh -n -t -q -o "BatchMode yes" -o "ConnectTimeout 5" -l $USER $SERVER '/home/username/timer.sh testvar;echo $?'`
  echo "return: [$ret]"
  if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "Success. Aborting"
       break
  fi
else
  printf "${i}\tUnable to connect to host\n";
fi
} < /dev/null; done
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I added my backup script to the question, along with your code updated. Its still not working as its still breaking input. Your example breaks on success, where i need it to continue through the list no matter what.

Comment: i modified your example by removing the `break` and in the `backup.sh` i added an `exit` at the end to force it to always `return 0`. Seems to be working.

Comment: @gorelative Oh, sorry, I think I misunderstood your original intent. I thought one successful `backup.sh` would be enough. But glad you got it working :)